# How can I multi-thread or multi-process a large itertools.combinations in python efficiently?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, combinations, python-itertools

## The Goal (simplest outline of a larger problem)

I am iteratively searching for a list of nearest sums of powers to a large integer.

**Some context**
I am new to multithreading. My understanding is that my current bottleneck could possibly be alleviated by multithreading. However, I am unsure if other methods are better suited to make further improvement.

## The Code

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import log, ceil

num = 26115155829

pwr = {n**p:str(n)+'^'+str(p) for n in range(9999,1,-1) for p in range(2,ceil(log(num,n)))}
pk = tuple(sorted(pwr.keys()))

sum2 = [(abs(num-(a+b)),' + '.join((pwr[a],pwr[b]))) for a,b in combinations(pk,2) if abs(num-(a+b)) < 99999]
sum3 = [(abs(num-(a+b+c)),' + '.join((pwr[a],pwr[b],pwr[c]))) for a,b,c in combinations(pk,3) if abs(num-(a+b+c)) < 99999]
```

**_ Description _**

```
 num: Example of a large integer (usually 10 to 18 digits long)
 pwr: Dictionary comprehension of possible base^exponent power pairs; 4 to 1 digits Base start as decreasing so as to overwrite duplicates with smaller base representation, Power is limited to be lower than target large integer
 sumN: Filtered list comprehension of the sum of N powers having a distance lower than ~100000 to the target
```

---

**Sample output**
`>>> print(*sorted(sum2)[:100],sep='\n')`

> ```
> (57, '4774^2 + 2966^3')
> (1052, '969^3 + 2932^3')
> (3654, '2052^3 + 2595^3')
> (5004, '8691^2 + 2964^3')
> (5560, '7012^2 + 2965^3')
> (8465, '7013^2 + 2965^3')
> (9492, '4775^2 + 2966^3')
> (9604, '4773^2 + 2966^3')
> (12379, '8692^2 + 2964^3')
> (13680, '1486^3 + 2837^3')
> (19043, '4776^2 + 2966^3')
> (19149, '4772^2 + 2966^3')
> (19583, '7011^2 + 2965^3')
> (22385, '8690^2 + 2964^3')
> (22492, '7014^2 + 2965^3')
> (24445, '1518^3 + 2828^3')
> (28596, '4777^2 + 2966^3')
> (28692, '4771^2 + 2966^3')
> (29764, '8693^2 + 2964^3')
> (30338, '843^3 + 2944^3')
> (30347, '1976^3 + 2640^3')
> (30581, '1072^3 + 120^5')
> (33604, '7010^2 + 2965^3')
> (36521, '7015^2 + 2965^3')
> (37919, '467^3 + 2963^3')
> (38151, '4778^2 + 2966^3')
> (38233, '4770^2 + 2966^3')
> (39764, '8689^2 + 2964^3')
> (46766, '791^3 + 2948^3')
> (47151, '8694^2 + 2964^3')
> (47623, '7009^2 + 2965^3')
> (47708, '4779^2 + 2966^3')
> (47772, '4769^2 + 2966^3')
> (50552, '7016^2 + 2965^3')
> (55208, '1021^3 + 2926^3')
> (57141, '8688^2 + 2964^3')
> (57267, '4780^2 + 2966^3')
> (57309, '4768^2 + 2966^3')
> (58112, '2157^3 + 2524^3')
> (59445, '1694^3 + 2770^3')
> (60912, '1748^3 + 2749^3')
> (61640, '7008^2 + 2965^3')
> (62883, '1733^3 + 2755^3')
> (64540, '8695^2 + 2964^3')
> (64585, '7017^2 + 2965^3')
> (66828, '4781^2 + 2966^3')
> (66844, '4767^2 + 2966^3')
> (73647, '855^3 + 2943^3')
> (74516, '8687^2 + 2964^3')
> (75655, '7007^2 + 2965^3')
> (76377, '4766^2 + 2966^3')
> (76391, '4782^2 + 2966^3')
> (78620, '7018^2 + 2965^3')
> (81931, '8696^2 + 2964^3')
> (85237, '1045^3 + 2923^3')
> (85268, '280^4 + 2713^3')
> (85908, '4765^2 + 2966^3')
> (85956, '4783^2 + 2966^3')
> (87470, '731^3 + 2952^3')
> (89668, '7006^2 + 2965^3')
> (91889, '8686^2 + 2964^3')
> (91936, '2328^3 + 2381^3')
> (92657, '7019^2 + 2965^3')
> (95437, '4764^2 + 2966^3')
> (95523, '4784^2 + 2966^3')
> (99324, '8697^2 + 2964^3')
> (99736, '638^3 + 2957^3')
> ```

`>>> print(*sorted(sum3)[:100],sep='\n')`

> ```
> (0, '1724^3 + 1893^3 + 2422^3')
> (0, '2798^2 + 6430^2 + 2965^3')
> (0, '462^2 + 8679^2 + 2964^3')
> (0, '5577^2 + 6666^2 + 2964^3')
> (0, '98^2 + 4773^2 + 2966^3')
> (1, '1485^2 + 9984^2 + 2963^3')
> (1, '1932^2 + 6741^2 + 2965^3')
> (1, '2499^2 + 6552^2 + 2965^3')
> (1, '2709^2 + 6468^2 + 2965^3')
> (1, '3549^2 + 6048^2 + 2965^3')
> (1, '5571^2 + 1510^3 + 2829^3')
> (2, '4454^2 + 9058^2 + 2963^3')
> (2, '4574^2 + 8998^2 + 2963^3')
> (3, '2133^2 + 4271^2 + 2966^3')
> (3, '2137^2 + 4269^2 + 2966^3')
> (3, '2682^2 + 9731^2 + 2963^3')
> (3, '295^3 + 127^4 + 2956^3')
> (3, '3693^2 + 9394^2 + 2963^3')
> (3, '4969^2 + 2095^3 + 2566^3')
> (3, '7022^2 + 7251^2 + 2963^3')
> (4, '1692^2 + 8525^2 + 2964^3')
> (4, '1717^2 + 8520^2 + 2964^3')
> (4, '2410^2 + 2302^3 + 2405^3')
> (4, '3148^2 + 217^4 + 2880^3')
> (4, '3533^2 + 2225^3 + 2471^3')
> (4, '3746^2 + 5928^2 + 2965^3')
> (4, '4642^2 + 5256^2 + 2965^3')
> (4, '560^2 + 6990^2 + 2965^3')
> (4, '5684^2 + 6575^2 + 2964^3')
> (4, '5901^2 + 9664^2 + 2962^3')
> (4, '6095^2 + 1318^3 + 2876^3')
> (4, '6100^2 + 6191^2 + 2964^3')
> (4, '6651^2 + 9164^2 + 2962^3')
> (4, '6892^2 + 2200^3 + 2489^3')
> (4, '7949^2 + 8064^2 + 2962^3')
> (5, '2397^2 + 6590^2 + 2965^3')
> (5, '2685^2 + 6478^2 + 2965^3')
> (5, '322^2 + 7005^2 + 2965^3')
> (5, '4031^2 + 9254^2 + 2963^3')
> (5, '4525^2 + 1006^3 + 2927^3')
> (5, '4947^2 + 4970^2 + 2965^3')
> (5, '6199^2 + 2335^3 + 2372^3')
> (5, '7441^2 + 8535^2 + 2962^3')
> (5, '8003^2 + 9512^2 + 2961^3')
> (5, '8932^2 + 9897^2 + 11^10')
> (6, '3^13 + 4604^2 + 2966^3')
> (6, '790^2 + 1211^3 + 2898^3')
> (7, '2192^2 + 531^3 + 2961^3')
> (7, '2858^2 + 3824^2 + 2966^3')
> (7, '2^6 + 4774^2 + 2966^3')
> (7, '346^2 + 318^4 + 2514^3')
> (7, '4135^2 + 9208^2 + 2963^3')
> (7, '4523^2 + 794^3 + 2947^3')
> (7, '543^3 + 2036^3 + 2597^3')
> (8, '1330^2 + 4585^2 + 2966^3')
> (8, '1687^2 + 4466^2 + 2966^3')
> (8, '209^3 + 9631^2 + 2963^3')
> (8, '2135^2 + 4270^2 + 2966^3')
> (8, '2422^2 + 8347^2 + 2964^3')
> (8, '2454^2 + 4095^2 + 2966^3')
> (8, '2870^2 + 3815^2 + 2966^3')
> (8, '4138^2 + 7643^2 + 2964^3')
> (8, '5357^2 + 8555^2 + 2963^3')
> (8, '5893^2 + 8195^2 + 2963^3')
> (8, '7743^2 + 8262^2 + 2962^3')
> (8, '7^2 + 4774^2 + 2966^3')
> (8, '854^2 + 4697^2 + 2966^3')
> (9, '2314^2 + 1623^3 + 2795^3')
> (9, '4739^2 + 2203^3 + 2488^3')
> (9, '4812^2 + 8873^2 + 2963^3')
> (9, '564^2 + 1301^3 + 2881^3')
> (9, '6318^2 + 2217^3 + 351^4')
> (10, '3376^2 + 2099^3 + 2564^3')
> (10, '7913^2 + 9587^2 + 2961^3')
> (10, '9748^2 + 1859^3 + 2696^3')
> (11, '8520^2 + 332^4 + 2404^3')
> (11, '8951^2 + 147^4 + 2946^3')
> (12, '1364^2 + 4575^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '1454^2 + 6860^2 + 2965^3')
> (12, '18^4 + 4763^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '2131^2 + 4272^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '2139^2 + 4268^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '2277^2 + 4196^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '2335^2 + 4164^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '2459^2 + 4092^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '2505^2 + 4064^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '3117^2 + 3616^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '3336^2 + 3415^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '455^2 + 130^4 + 2956^3')
> (12, '488^2 + 4749^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '696^2 + 4723^2 + 2966^3')
> (12, '9139^2 + 9864^2 + 2960^3')
> (12, '9427^2 + 1308^3 + 2876^3')
> (13, '1646^2 + 8534^2 + 2964^3')
> (13, '273^2 + 8687^2 + 2964^3')
> (13, '5152^2 + 1400^3 + 2858^3')
> (13, '533^2 + 1228^3 + 2895^3')
> (13, '6728^2 + 62^5 + 2930^3')
> (13, '7160^2 + 506^3 + 2960^3')
> (14, '4088^2 + 2211^3 + 2482^3')
> ```

Comment: I haven't looked at your problem in too much detail, but from just a quick glance I can tell that mutithreading won't help your performance at all. Your code is pure Python and CPU bound (not IO bound), so if you start up multiple threads, they will always be contending for the GIL (the Global Interpreter Lock). Only one thread at a time can run Python code, so there is zero chance that you'll get improvement for your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

### Will multi-threading help?

As @Blckknght noted, CPython's multi-threading is limited by the [GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).  Since only one thread can run at a time, threading isn't helpful for improving the performance of CPU bound code?

### Will multi-processing help?

Yes, the [multi-processing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) is great for improving the performance of CPU bound code, but only for problems that:

1) Can be partitioned into independent sub-problems

2) Does not have communication overhead that offsets the advantages of parallel processing

### Can combinations be partitioned into sub-problems?

A single run of the *combinations* iterator isn't easily partitioned (it doesn't have a way to start in the middle of an iteration sequence).

However, you can run `combinations(pk, 2)` and `combinations(pk, 3)` in separate processes.